# Uniqueness constraint for elements of arrays in the entire table

Tags: postgresql, array

In the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    email           varchar[],
    ...
);
```

I'd like to ensure that no two users have the same e-mail. I'm not sure how the `UNIQUE` constraint interacts with array data types. What's the appropriate way to ensure uniqueness? Or is this an anti-pattern and should I just declare another `emails` table instead?

Comment: Normalize your data model, and you can add a regular unique constraint

Comment: You cannot do that. Don't use non-scalar types like arrays if you want constraints on the elements.

Comment: A normalized schema is the safe, canonical way to implement this. There are workarounds ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017013/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you said, I'd create an emails table that refer to the users.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user         ... ,
    username        varchar(255),
    ... ,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE emails (
    id_email        ... ,
    id_user         ... ,
    email           varchar(255),
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_email),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user
      FOREIGN KEY(id_user) 
      REFERENCES users(id_user)
);
```

Then in the emails table you can add a unique constraint on id_user, id_email.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY xak1_unique_id_user_and_email_ix
ON emails (id_user, id_email);

ALTER TABLE emails ADD CONSTRAINT xak1_unique_id_user_and_email UNIQUE
                      USING INDEX xak1_unique_id_user_and_email_ix;
```

P.S. I don't work usually on PostgreSQL, for the syntax I referred to [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-unique-constraint/)